# elasticsearch : Class not found exception

Tags: elasticsearch

My elastic search is running.

But when I do this :

```
curl -XPUT "http://127.0.0.1:9200/movies/movie/1" -d'
 {
     "title": "The Godfather",
     "director": "Francis Ford Coppola",
     "year": 1972
 }'
```

This error is coming.

{"error":"IndexCreationException[[movies] failed to create index]; nested: NoClassDefFoundError[Could not initialize class org.elasticsearch.index.codec.postingsformat.PostingFormats]; ","status":500}

Answer (score 1):

It could happen if you mix jar files and bring other Lucene dependencies then the ones required or if you only add elasticsearch jar to your Java project.

It's hard to say here as we don't know how you installed elasticsearch and which version you are using.

Same command works fine for me.